# How do I indent all of the lines after a line?

Tags: python, string

Example:

```
def print_text():
    print("Here's some text")
    print("Here's some more text")
    print("Here's the rest of the text")

print_text()

# Hypothetical command that indents all of the following text
start_indenting()

print_text()

# Hypothetical command that stops indenting.
stop_indenting()

print_text()
```

Desired Output:

```
Here's some text
Here's some more text
Here's the rest of the text
    Here's some text
    Here's some more text
    Here's the rest of the text
Here's some text
Here's some more text
Here's the rest of the text
```

I'm looking for something that indents all text after it without actually changing the text or commands. I have no clue how I would achieve this. Editing each print statement in the given method (print_text) would be a last resort considering my method in the program I'm using this for has a ton of print statements. I've looked at textwrap but it isn't able to do what I need.

Comment: Have you looked at https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.indent yet?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I have but sadly it isn't able to indent text from a method from what I've seen. I considered trying some things with it but it didn't work.

Comment: It's able to indent *any* text.

Comment: I know but it doesn't have the start_indenting() and stop_indenting() function im looking for

Comment: So your question is not how to actually indent text, but how to manage a context in which the indentation level is greater than outside the context.

Comment: Yep that’s exactly what I was wondering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need it locally (in a single file), you may override the print function:

```
from builtins import print as default_print

print = default_print

def indented_print(*args,  prefix='    ', **kwargs):
    default_print(prefix, *args, **kwargs)

def start_indenting():
    global print
    print = indented_print
    
def stop_indenting():
    global print
    print = default_print
    
def print_text():
    print("Here's some text")
    print("Here's some more text")
    print("Here's the rest of the text")
    
   
print_text()

# Hypothetical command that indents all of the following text
start_indenting()

print_text()

# Hypothetical command that stops indenting.
stop_indenting()

print_text()
```

You could also affect all prints (not only in this module), with

```
def start_indenting(): 
    builtins.print = indented_print
```

but users of your module may not expect it, and it might be hard to traceback in case of problem.

Comment: Only works for single line prints. `print("line1\nline2")` will only indent the first line.

Comment: @Wups you're right: using textwrap.indent (as suggested in other comments) within indented_print will fix this.

Comment: How would I use this with inputs? I've noticed inputs don't work with this which is completely understandable since that wasn't my original question, so I created one, but where you do default_print(prefix, *args, **kwargs) in indented_print what would i do for default_input() for my input code?

Comment: Do you mean that `val=input("type something here:")` should also use the indentation?

Comment: Yes but I got it working. I was missing a return statement lmao. I really appreciate your help this is insanely helpful for the project I'm working on!

Answer (score 4):

I have used a context manager for a similar problem statement:

```
class Indenter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.level = 0
        
    def __enter__(self):
        self.level += 1
        return self
    
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.level -= 1
        
    def print(self, text):
        print('\t'*self.level + text)


with Indenter() as indent:
    indent.print('hi!')
    with indent:
        indent.print('hello')
        with indent:
            indent.print('bonjour')
    indent.print('hey')
```

Class `Indenter` can be customized.

Comment: This could also be implemented in such a way as to affect the built-in `print()` function which would make using `indent.print()` unnecessary (os it would be even easier to use).

Answer (score 3):

There is no such command without imports. You can code it yourself:

```
def my_print(text, indent=0, space=4):
    if indent:
        print(indent * space * ' ', end='', sep='')
    print(text)


def print_text(indent = 0):
    my_print("Here's some text", indent)
    my_print("Here's some more text", indent)
    my_print("Here's the rest of the text", indent)


print_text()
print_text(1)
print_text(2)
print_text(3)
print_text(1)
print_text()
```

Output:

```
Here's some text
Here's some more text
Here's the rest of the text
    Here's some text
    Here's some more text
    Here's the rest of the text        
        Here's some text
        Here's some more text
        Here's the rest of the text    
            Here's some text
            Here's some more text      
            Here's the rest of the text
    Here's some text
    Here's some more text
    Here's the rest of the text        
Here's some text
Here's some more text      
Here's the rest of the text
```

Obviously you would need to add handling for multiline `text` (maybe splitting and applying it to all lines) as well as for formatting if your use case needs those.

With imports you can use [textwrap.indent](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.indent).

Comment: This would work, but the issue is the method I'm using has a ton of print statements which would make this extremely tedious and time consuming. I'm willing to use imports but editing each statement would be rough. If it comes down to it, though, this presents a very good solution. Thank you!